# Supremum / Holder Norm Inequality Proof

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, continuity, normed-spaces

For $\alpha$-Holder continuous paths $X$ and $X'$  (ie $X,X' \in C^{\alpha}$), we have the following inequalities

$$
||X||_{\infty} \leq |X_0| + T^{\alpha}||X||_{\alpha}
$$
and
$$
||X-X'||_{\infty} \leq |X_0 - X'_0| + T^{\alpha}||X-X'||_{\alpha}
$$

These inequalities are briefly mentioned in the notes of a course that I am following but are not proven. Would someone please mind walking me through the proof? Thanks

The following are the definitions used in these inequalities:

$X_{s,t} = X_t-X_s$ for all $s,t \in [0,T]$

$||X||_{\alpha} = \sup_{0\leq s<t\leq T}\frac{|X_{s,t}|}{|s-t|^{\alpha}}$

The path $X$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous if $||X||_{\alpha} < \infty$

The supremum norm is defined as $||X||_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in [0,T]}|X_t|$

Thanks

Comment: $\lvert X_t \rvert \le \lvert X_0 \rvert + \lvert X_t - X_0 \rvert$

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the hint. I now have the following: $X_t = X_0 + X_{0,t}$. Thus by the triangle inequality we get $|X_t| = |X_0 + X_{0,t}| \leq |X_0| + |X_{0,t}|$. Then applying the definition of the Holder norm we get $|X_t| \leq |X_0| + ||X||_{\alpha}|t-s|^{\alpha}$. Then since $|t-s| \leq T^{\alpha}$ this becomes  $|X_t| \leq |X_0| + ||X||_{\alpha}|T^{\alpha}$ which is the RHS of the desired inequality. But how does the supremum norm come into this? It feels like im missing something very obvious. Thanks

Comment: Take the supremum over $t$.

Comment: @Adam thank you so much thats incredibly helpful, not sure how I didn't notice that!